# What program was used in Kojima's Death Stranding to create the 3D scans of people?

Tags: camera, 3d-meshes, motion-capture

I've been unable to find out what program Hideo Kojima used to create his 3D scans of people in his game Death Stranding and presumably Metal Gear V as well. Here is a video of the scanning in progrees (Starts at 4:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlMpN26ts7s).

Comment: The problem of "how they did it" questions is that, often, only the people who worked on it can answer properly. Are you not more interested in how you can do it? Well, I guess in this case that falls back to asking for tools, which is off-topic here. Try [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Tell me if you ask there, I might have a couple suggestions.

Comment: The second problem with these questions is that using the same program won't magically enable you to create the same quality of content.  A program is just a tool.  Using the same hammer as a master carpenter doesn't make you a master carpenter too, and the same goes for programs.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus yes im aware that using their tools wont let me make things as masterfully than them, but its a place to start

Comment: @Theraot the point of this "how they did it" question is so i can know how to do it, yes

Comment: Then you should ask how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Death Stranding was created wit the help of the Sony Playstation Visual Arts Services Group, located in San Diego. They did the body scans and motion capture for the game and the trailer.

The only thing I have been able to figure out about their photogrammetry and motion capture solution, aside from the rig shown in the linked video, is that they use a a proprietary software compatible with Autodesk Maya and Motion Builder.